# Why when i edit PATH(enviroment variable) in cmd, l can't find changes in system property, but i can find in cmd?(windows10))

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, windows-10

here is the path before edit:

```
echo %path%
```

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Then i use cmd order `path=%path%C:\Test;` to add a new root to path.

After that, i `echo %path%` again, and i got this:

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Test;
```

It looks good,Gight?.But when i go into system property.

I got this:

[image: Problem:]

Obviously, the new root `C:\Test` is not showing in the system property.

I want to know why and how to fix the problem.

Comment: `PATH` is usually not terminated by a `;`, it should be a semicolon-separated list of paths. Anyway, changing it with `set` only affects the current Command Prompt instance…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you were hoping to do, specifically appending to the existing System Environment `%Path%` variable, this is how I'd recommend you do it:

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```bash
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlset\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V Path 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Path "%HC:\Test;" /M
```

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bash
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query
 "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlset\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V Path
 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Path "%%HC:\Test;" /M
```

Please note: to do this, you'll need to run your [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) elevated, i.e. "Run as administrator". Also this is designed to add your new directory location, **only** if there is already non space content within that variables value, *(if there isn't your system is already broken)*. You should also note that the new variable content will only be available for future `cmd.exe` instances, not any currently running ones, *(which were loaded prior to your change)*. If you wanted it available globally and local to the running session, you'd need to also include the separate command, `Set "Path=%Path%C:\Test;"`